# Problema - CSS animation

Tags: html, css

Olá, pessoal. Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento web e queria resolver um problema que pode até ser básico pra alguns de vocês. Resumindo, não consigo fazer o VS code compilar essa parte do código css, mais precisamente a parte do "animate", onde claramente quando jogado no VSCode não há compilação.

```
box-area li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
```

No vídeo-curso que estava vendo o instrutor usou exatamente esses parâmetros. Alguém teria alguma sugestão do porque no animation o "animate" não é identificado pelo compilador?

Comment: Além disso, você precisa declarar o `animate` com `@keyframes`, dá uma olhada na [documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dito o comentário acima, talvez voce tenha esquecido dois detalhes:

1. Adicionar a referencia correta no ***CSS***, se 'box-area' for uma **class** você deve colocar um ponto antes indicando **'.box-area'** se um **id** um jogo-da-velha/hashtag **'#box-area'** do elemento alvo;
2. Adicionar @keyframes no seu `<style>`.

links para estudos:

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

```css
@keyframes animate0 {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}
.box-area-0 {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        list-style: none;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation: animate0 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  from {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}
  to {background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);}
}
.box-area-1 {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        list-style: none;
        top: 30px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        animation: animate1 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-area-0">
</div>

<div class="box-area-1">
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, perfeito! Graças ao seu código consegui entender o problema. Obrigado mesmo!